# One program in a Branch will not Reconize ONE REFERENCE

Tags: c#, branching-and-merging, azure-devops, tfvc

I've created a branch and after realizing that all i needed to do was add the .dll of the other programs,life is looking up ;). Anyway, after 5 hours it's time to hit the overflow again for a final issue and I will feel as if I accomplished something.

I've created a branch and all the nessesserry programs that are to be worked on are in the branch, and all the references are copied and pasted as .dlls, feel like i did something. ;)

Anyway, I've got one program that will not reconize one dll or any built in reference or any Nuget packages, believe me i've tried every thing under the sun, and i mean everything to my knowledge and after 5 hours it's time to get to the StackOverflow.

Please see my two snap shots and give me a hint as to want in the wold to do. Now, every program had to have it's references reset and no issues but this one is a rouge, I've removed it, deleted it, re-added it, what's next? I'm lost.

Please advise.

[[image: The One that will not recognize one reference even if i reference it][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9CMv.jpg)

[image: What the rest of the programs look like "YES I CHECKED VERSIONS They're all 4.5"]

### Here is the output.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: PartsProcessor, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CadDetials, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: UtilFile, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\CadDetials\Manager.cs(1,7,1,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AlumCloudDrawing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\CadDetials\Manager.cs(17,28,17,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DrawingBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3>  UtilFile -> W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\UtilFile\bin\Debug\UtilFile.dll
1>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\PartsProcessor\Processors\PartsProcessor.cs(58,21,58,38): warning CS0414: The field 'PartProcessor.W_BLOCKS_PER_LITE' is assigned but its value is never used
1>  PartsProcessor -> W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\PartsProcessor\bin\Debug\PartsProcessor.dll
4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Optimization, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
5>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CutSheet, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
6>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ElevationMaker, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
7>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Estimate, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
6>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\ElevationMaker\ElevationMaker.csproj(183,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567.
8>------ Rebuild All started: Project: PartsList, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
4>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\Optimization\OptimizedParts.cs(1,7,1,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AlumCloudDrawing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\Optimization\OptimizedParts.cs(19,35,19,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DrawingBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
9>------ Rebuild All started: Project: LabelMaker, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
8>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\PartsList\MaterialList.cs(1,7,1,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AlumCloudDrawing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
8>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\PartsList\MaterialList.cs(18,33,18,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DrawingBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
10>------ Rebuild All started: Project: AlumCloudDrawing, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
9>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\LabelMaker\Manager.cs(1,7,1,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AlumCloudDrawing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
9>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\LabelMaker\Labels.cs(1,7,1,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AlumCloudDrawing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
9>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\LabelMaker\ILabels.cs(8,70,8,86): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AlumCloudDrawing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
9>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\LabelMaker\ILabels.cs(9,103,9,119): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AlumCloudDrawing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
9>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\LabelMaker\Labels.cs(38,45,38,54): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SheetInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
9>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\LabelMaker\Labels.cs(43,41,43,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SheetInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
9>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\LabelMaker\Labels.cs(18,27,18,34): error CS0535: 'Labels' does not implement interface member 'ILabels.GetPDF(AlumCloudDrawing.SheetInfo)'
9>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\LabelMaker\Labels.cs(18,27,18,34): error CS0535: 'Labels' does not implement interface member 'ILabels.GetSheets(AlumCloudDrawing.SheetInfo)'
10>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\AlumCloudDrawing\AlumCloudDrawing.csproj(138,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets.
5>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\CutSheet\CutSheet.cs(1,7,1,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AlumCloudDrawing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
5>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\CutSheet\CutSheet.cs(18,29,18,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DrawingBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
7>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\Estimate\Estimate.cs(1,7,1,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AlumCloudDrawing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
7>W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\Estimate\Estimate.cs(16,29,16,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DrawingBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
11>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BackendSandbox, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
11>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "DataImporter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".
11>  BackendSandbox -> W:\Users\Erik Little\Source\Workspaces\WorkSpace\AlumCloud\Main\BackEnd\BackendSandbox\bin\Debug\BackendSandbox.exe
========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 8 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the same snap shot at VSO Main base source code, not the branch.

[image: VSO-Main-Base-Code]

Comment: Check the framework version of the AlumCloudDrawing project in project properties.

Comment: We won't get anywhere with these screenshots. Do a clean build and provide the build output from the output window.

Comment: I did that Jon, that was one of the things I read

Comment: @spender I posted what you asked for. It seems tricky, because the NuGet is not telling the truth I did all that, removed and then added back, and counted line by line and all dll / packages are there.

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com How did you add the nuget packages (and references to the DLLs) to the other project? If they are nuget packages, they must be added by nuget, not by cut'n'paste. If they are references to other projects, they should be added as a reference to the project, not to the DLL output of the project.

Comment: It also looks like you're targeting .net framework version v4.5 in some of the projects but v4.5.1 in others. This is causing issues in BackendSandbox.

Comment: All projects are 4.5 I swear! I think I confused you, I did not cut and paste the NuGet, I ran the NuGet reload, it makes no sense to me, every project had the same issues I addressed them and when I got to this one it bombed out on me, it make no sense. How can I reference a built in type like System.XML and it show the Triangle? Every single one of those references' have triangles, I am lost for words. Now in the Main solution it does not have these triangles but it does in the branch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109092/discussion-between-alumcloud-com-and-spender).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the Package Restore is checked.

[image]

2. Make sure you have installed the latest Nuget version. https://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget
3. Make sure you are using Automatic Package Restore. http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue, I deleted the entire branch , re added it and this time it brought over now only the NuGet project packages but it brought over the solution large NuGet solution packages. I clicked on one program and it assigned this program to be my solution. I fixed all the references and build. This automatically retrieved all the NuGet packages. And now it works like a charm! I think during my learning process i am very sure i messed something up because it was a learning process, but the second time took only minutes and whamO it works. thanks for the help every body